# Python PYQT QLineEdit font size

Tags: python, pyqt

I am creating a form using PYQT

```
self.texteditor1= QtGui.QLineEdit(self) 
self.texteditor1.setFixedWidth(560)
```

I wanted to know that how to increase font size of texteditor in above case ?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
f = self.texteditor1.font()
f.setPointSize(27) # sets the size to 27
self.texteditor1.setFont(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `pointSize` property of lineedit font.

```
self.texteditor1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
font = self.texteditor1.font()      # lineedit current font
font.setPointSize(32)               # change it's size
self.texteditor1.setFont(font)      # set font
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell that how to wrap text in the QLineEdit box ?

Comment: That won't happen on **line**. You will have to use different widget. Read some docs and if you find a problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

```
self.input_field = QLineEdit()
self.input_field.setFont(QFont('Arial', 15))  # this is what you need!
```

**Full answer**:

```
# import libraries you need!
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # some code

        self.input_field = QLineEdit()
        self.input_field.setFont(QFont('Arial', 15))  # this is what you need!

        # some code

        container = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, because it may reset the family, weight and bold properties of the existing font as well as its point-size. The other answers show a more robust way to change the point-size.